# python ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] El host remoto cerró a la fuerza una conexión existente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un código Python que realiza descarga paralelas por medio de rangos pero recibo el error del título con un link en especial (con los links de google) y no se por qué.

Ya he intentado agregar manejador de contexto para que entre rangos cierre la conexión pero no ha funcionado, estaba pensando en agregar proxys a la descarga pero eso le quitaría esencia al programa:

```
    import urllib.request
    import threading
    import time
    rangos_a_unir={}
    rangos_unir_comprobacion={}
                      print("=====================================================")
    print("CREADOR JHOAN BARRERA")
    print("=====================================================")
    extension=input("ESCRIBE LA EXTENSION DEL ARCHIVO: ")
    def peso_archivo_rangos_unir(url):

        c=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

        c=int(c.getheader('Content-Length'))
        print("TAMAÑO DEL ARCHIVO",c)

        c=int(c//50)+1
        d=c
        for i in range(50):
            if i==0:
                rangos_a_unir[0]=c
            else:

                rangos_a_unir[(c-d)+1]=c
            c=c+d
        print(rangos_a_unir)
        iniciar_descarga_paralela(url,rangos_unir_comprobacion)

    def descarga_rangos(url,a,b):
        
        data= urllib.request.Request(url)

        data.add_header('Range',f'bytes={str(a)}-{str(b)}' )

        data=urllib.request.urlopen(data)
        #try:
        data=data.read()
        rangos_unir_comprobacion[a]=data
        print(len(rangos_unir_comprobacion))

        #except:
        #   rangos_unir_comprobacion[a]=data

        

    def reconstruccion_datos(rangos):
        while True:
            
            
            if len(rangos)==50:
                print("==============")
                print("claves")
                print("===========")
                print(rangos.keys())

                print("===========")
                print("RANGOS ORDENADOS")
                print("==============")
                lista_rangos_ordenados=sorted(rangos)
                with open("archivo_descargado.{}".format(extension), "wb") as f:
                    for i in range(len(lista_rangos_ordenados)):
                        f.write(rangos[lista_rangos_ordenados[i]])

                break
            

    def iniciar_descarga_paralela(url,rangos_unir_comprobacion):
        a=0
        for i in rangos_a_unir:
            try:
                thread=threading.Thread(target=descarga_rangos, args=(url,i,rangos_a_unir[i],))
                thread.start()
            except:
                thread=threading.Thread(target=descarga_rangos, args=(url,i,rangos_a_unir[i],))
                thread.start()
                print("HUBO ERROR")
            a+=1
            time.sleep(1.5)
        thread2=threading.Thread(target=reconstruccion_datos, args=(rangos_unir_comprobacion,))
        thread2.start()



    peso_archivo_rangos_unir(f"{input('ESCRIBE TU URL: ')}")
```